# How to stop UIActivityIndicator when Core Data save operation is finished

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code that I would like to start animating a `UIActivityIndicator`, save a `ManagedObjectContext`, and once the save is completed, stop animating the `UIActivityIndicator`. Here is the code that I have right now:

```
    activityIndicator.hidden = false
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, animations: {
        self.titleLabel.text = "Importing from GPX File"
        self.descriptionLabel.hidden = true
        self.okButton.hidden = true
        self.cancelButton.hidden = true
    })

    importFromGPXFile()

    activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
```

The method that does the core data save operation is `importFromGPXFile()`. How do I let the activity indicator know that the save operation has finished and that it should stop animating?

Comment: Go for delegate or completion handler closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try -

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
importFromGPXFile()

activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
});
```

You will have to take care that a run-loop will be completed immediately to actually show animating indicator. Using dispatch_async for main queue will do it.

Comment: I don't understand much about dispatch_async and GCD, but this code seems to work for me. Thanks